# How to reuse custom events

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building up a visualization using D3 that has some quite rich user interaction. At the moment I've got a background canvas that supports the following events:

- click
- double click
- long click
- drag (used for panning)
- zoom (pinch + wheel)

I'm trying to manage all these events, and I've got to the point where I'm starting to repeat my code for different parts of the application. As an example, within the application:

1. A double click should not trigger the single click action
2. A double click should also ignore the fact the user may have accidentally dragged slightly

So I've devised an approach to do this. What I'm now interesting in, is whether or not there is a technique allowing me to re-use the event I've created (a bit like you create a `d3.behaviour.zoom` and use `.call`).

So to illustrate

---

**Click + Double Click**

I have some behaviour to start a timer on a click which will trigger the single click behavior after a timeout. If there is another click and the timer still exists then cancel it and run the double click behavior instead. I'm currently hooking this up like so:

```
d3.select(target)
  .append("circle")
  .on("click", function (d) {
    __onClick(d, this);
  });
```

I've then defined `__onClick` like so:

```
var __onClick = function (d) {
    var self = this;

    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
    d3.event.stopPropagation();            // prevent event bubbling

    // If we already have a timer then we need to execute
    // a double click behavior event
    if (self.__timer) {
        console.log("dblclick simulated");
        clearTimeout(self.__timer);
        self.__timer = null;
        self.DoADoubleClickThingy();
        return;
    }

    // Start a single click operation
    self.__timer = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("click simulated");
        self.__timer = null;
        self.DoSingleClickThingy();
    }, 250);
};
```

So I guess I'm wondering, is it possible to create something like the following to register a new behavior? I'm currently trying to go through the `D3` code but don't quite understand it enough to know if this is possible.

```
var clicks = d3.behaviours.customDoubleClick
             .clickSpeed(250)
             .on("click", function() { self.DoSingleClickThingy(); })
             .on("dblclick", function() { self.DoADoubleClickThingy(); });

d3.select(target)
      .append("circle")
      .call(clicks);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through the [zoom](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/behavior/zoom.js) code on github for `D3` again I realised it wasn't quite as complicated as I thought - especially when I realised that `call` actually just executes the `zoom` function. Here's the solution I put together, that I'm hoping to put on github or similar:

```
var custom = { };
custom.events = function () {

    var clickTimeout = 3000;        // The timeout that is used to distinguish between a single and double click
    var clickTimer;                 // The timer that is used for a single click event

    var dispatch = d3.dispatch("click", "dblclick");

    function events(g) {

        g.on("click", clicked)
         .on("dblclick", doubleClicked);
    };

    function clicked(d, i) {

        if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;      // Ignore if a drag operation is taking place
        d3.event.stopPropagation();                 // Prevent the event going any further

        // If we already have a timer then we need to execute
        // a double click behaviour event
        if (clickTimer) {
            clearTimeout(clickTimer);
            clickTimer = null;
            dispatch.dblclick.call(this, d, i);
            return;
        }

        // Setup the timer for single click
        clickTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            // Trigger a single click
            clickTimer = null;
            dispatch.click.call(this, d, i);
        }, clickTimeout);
    };

    function doubleClicked(d, i) {
        // Suppress the natural double click event
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
    };

    // Return the bound events
    return d3.rebind(events, dispatch, "on");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a factory function that, given the type of behaviour you want, returns a function that installs the appropriate handlers:

```
function mkClicks(type) {
  // figure out what "self" should be depending on type
  return function(sel) {
    sel.on("click", function() { self.DoSingleClickThingy(); })
       .on("dblclick", function() { self.DoADoubleClickThingy(); });
  }
}

d3.select(target)
  .append("circle")
  .call(mkClicks(typeA));
```

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for the answer. Yeah, I've been studying zoom a bit more and I think that's basically what it's doing. I'm trying to put something together and I think I've got the pattern working (will post an answer when I have), just fighting with mousedown breaking my clicks for some reason.

Comment: You can also use the "usual" D3 resuable function pattern, which amounts to the same thing. It really depends on how much flexibility you need.

Comment: I've added a more specific question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588871/double-click-timer-is-always-null-when-mousedown-mouseup-registered about the particular issue I've got, going to post the pattern that I've used up here too. Hopefully it's useful to someone else.