# Double click timer is always null when mousedown/mouseup registered

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a re-usable D3 events function that provides some slightly richer eventing regarding clicks + double clicks. The idea being that a double click should not fire a single click. I managed to get that working, but now I've introduced a 3rd aspect (the long click) the basic behavior seems to be breaking and I can't figure out why.

```js
var custom = { };
custom.events = function () {

    var clickTimeout = 3000;        // The timeout that is used to distinguish between a single and double click
    var longClickTimeout = 1000;    // The timeout that is used to identify a long press
    var clickTimer;                 // The timer that is used for a single click event
    var longTimer;                  // The timer for a long press

    var dispatch = d3.dispatch("click", "dblclick", "longclick", "mousedown", "mouseup");

    function events(g) {
  
        g.on("mousedown", mousedown)
         .on("mouseup", mouseup)
         .on("click", clicked)
         .on("dblclick", doubleClicked);
    };

    /**
     * Function that's called when an item is clicked. This function
     * handles the advanced behaviour and farms out calls for both single
     * and double click style events
     * @params {object} d - The D3 datum
     * @aparams {number} i - The index of the datum
     */
    function clicked(d, i) {
        
        if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;      // Ignore if a drag operation is taking place
        d3.event.stopPropagation();                 // Prevent the event going any further

        // If we already have a timer then we need to execute
        // a double click behaviour event
        console.log("Click Timer : " + clickTimer);
        if (clickTimer) {
            console.log("Clearing Click Timer : " + clickTimer);
            clearTimeout(clickTimer);
            clickTimer = null;
            dispatch.dblclick.call(this, d, i);
            return;
        }

        // Setup the timer for single click
        clickTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            // Trigger a single click
            clickTimer = null;
            dispatch.click.call(this, d, i);
        }, clickTimeout);
        console.log("Creating Click Timer : " + clickTimer);
    };

    /*
     * Function that's called when an item is double clicked. In
     * this case the function is just suppressed
     */
    function doubleClicked(d, i) {
        // Suppress the natural double click event
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
    };

    function mousedown(d, i) {
        // Set up the long press timer
        longTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            longClickTimeout = null;
            dispatch.longclick.call(this, d, i);
        }, longClickTimeout);

        console.log("Creating Long Timer : " + longTimer);
        // Trigger a mouse down event
        dispatch.mousedown.call(this, d, i);
    }

    function mouseup(d, i) {
        // Cancel the long timer (it should have already fired if it needed to)
        if (longTimer) {
            console.log("Clearing Long Timer : " + longTimer);
            clearTimeout(longTimer);
            clickTimer = null;
        }

        dispatch.mouseup.call(this, d, i);
    }

    // Return the bound events
    return d3.rebind(events, dispatch, "on");
};

var events = custom.events()
.on("click", function() { console.log("click"); })
.on("dblclick", function() { console.log("dblclick"); });

d3.select("svg")
.append("circle")
.attr("r", 150)
.attr("cx", 150)
.attr("cy", 150)
.style("fill", "red")
.call(events);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
```

You can see in the above code snippet what I've put together, with my debugging output in there. If you try double clicking on the circle with the console visible it seems as though the `clickTimer` is always null even when double clicking.

If however you comment out the `on` registration for either `mousedown` or `mouseup` on lines **13** and **14** respectively:

```
 g.on("mousedown", mousedown)
         .on("mouseup", mouseup)
         .on("click", clicked)
         .on("dblclick", doubleClicked);
```

then everything works as expected, however I can't seem to spot any side affects of the two functions. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: It sounds like the actual events are interfering, as some events trigger multiple of your handlers. I would implement sophisticated behaviour like this purely in terms of `mouseup` and `mousedown` as that gives you the highest level of control and allows you to handle `click` and `dblclick` events (which you can detect manually) as well.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Yeah I could do, and that's the fallback plan. The thing that confuses me is that the codepath seems correct, and if it weren't for the fact I have a timer that I don't expect to be null, I think it'd all work absolutely fine.

Comment: You're setting `clickTimer` to `null` in the `mouseup` handler where you're checking `longTimer`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: face + palm... not sure how highlighting all occurrences of `clickTimer` didn't pick that up! Add a quick answer if you want +15 rep. It's deserved out of my stupidity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `clickTimer` to `null` in the `mouseup` handler where you're checking `longTimer`. Correcting that fixes the behaviour.